# C# type of variable. (variable)

Tags: c#, types

I have an array of Items:

```
Item[] ItemsOut;
```

The problem is I have some derived types `Item`, like `EquipItem`. They are in this array too.

I have an `AddItem` function for both of the `Item` and `EquipItem` classes.

```
Inventory.AddItem(AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i]......);
```

The idea is that in case my array is of type `Item[]` so it is always adding Items like normal `Item`.

My current solution is working and it's:

```
if (AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i].GetType() == typeof(EquipItem))
{
    Inventory.AddItem((EquipItem)AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i], AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i].number);
}
else
{
    Inventory.AddItem(AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i], AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i].number);
}
```

But if I have 100500 child classes I will be forced to do 100500 `if` statements.

How to make this automatic? Something like:

```
Inventory.AddItem((AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i].GetType())AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i], AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i].number);
```

or

```
Inventory.AddItem(AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i] as AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i].GetType(), AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i].number);
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
Type t = AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i].GetType();
Inventory.AddItem((t)AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i].number);
```

But it causes a "variable used as a type" error, when I DO NEED to use it as a type. Not variable of course, but its value.

Comment: Why are you casting at all? What does `AddItem(EquipItem)` do differently to `AddItem(Item)`?

Comment: Fundimentally what you're trying to do is just something that the C# type system is not particularly well suited to handle.  See [this series of articles](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) on the topic that goes into some depth in explaining why this is a problem, what some of the solutions are, and why none of them are particularly great (in C# anyway).

Comment: AddItem(EquipItem) adding Item and makes it equipable, nonstackable, e.t.c. When AddItem(Item) makes it usual item. Thank you a lot for articles. And btw this moderator job just awesome, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @MirBot so you have 100500 different `AddItem` methods?

Comment: The main is that, what will you do with this list later on? Because if you can get the type of item while adding it, you can also get that type after adding it to the list.

Comment: @Lashane Probably not, but i mean if i add some derived types Item i dont want to change anything, trying to make my code that good as i can. I really like this community moderating and answering speed. Just want you to know.

Comment: why does `Inventory.AddItem` make any changes to objects? It probably should call some abstract method, which is overridden in every child class

Comment: @Shaharyar AddItem(EquipItem) function makes it equipable, that does allow me to equip it obviously. I already got some ideas after all help, i think thats already enough, but still interested if c# supports something like this.

Comment: @Lashane hm. Good idea. Thank you. I didnt think about that, my first serious project, to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, unless you have two methods named AddItem (one for Item and another for EquipItem) you don't need to cast your ItemsOut, just use
`Inventory.AddItem(AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i], AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i].number);`

Second, you can't do this:

```
Type t = AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i].GetType();
addItem((t)AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i]
```

because `t` is an instance of the class `Type`, you can only cast using the type name like `(EquipItem) AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i]`

And finally, unless you are having performance issues, don't ever try to optimize your code. Doing so is what we call [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

So, check if you have a method `AddItem(EquipItem equipItem)`. If you don't, you don't need to check it's type and cast the Item to EquipItem. Hope I could help you.

**EDIT** the best thing I can think that can improve your code is clearing it a bit, like this:

```
var item = AllRecipes.Recipes[curPage].ItemsOut[i];
if (item is EquipItem)
{
    Inventory.AddItem((EquipItem) item, item.number);
}
else
{
    Inventory.AddItem(item, item.number);
}
```

Comment: AddItem(EquipItem equipItem) - yes, ofc i got this method. You helped me alot with "unless you are having performance issues, don't ever try to optimize your code". Thats sounds crazy for such Perfectionist as me but i will read the article and probably will understand that this is right.

Comment: @mir-bot Yes it is difficult to comprehend that but trust me, it will help you a lot. While optimize your code is not desirable, improving its readability is encouraged. In this case, my last edit may help.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here should be not to make anything know the difference between an `Item`, an `EquipItem` (or for that matter any old `FooItem`).

If they all derive from `Item` and the array is typed as `Item[]` then those subclasses can be added to the array without issue

```
var item = new Item();
var equip = new EquipItem(); // where EquipItem inherits from Item;
var array = new Item[]{ item,equipItem}; // no error here
```

If you have a single `AddItem` method, which adds to this array and performs some action based on the type, again the calling code should not know anything about the type - perhaps some virtual method which does some action when added to the list

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual void AddedToList(){}
}    

public class EquipItem
{
    public override void AddedToList()
    {
        // behaviour specific to EquipItem
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is i using unity and my Item[] array filling by GetComponents function which returns array of Items

Comment: @MirBot I dont see how that makes any difference to this answer.

Comment: That's called Polymorphism and if that did not work the way @Jamiec mentioned, no one of us would be using C# itself.

Comment: @Jamiec they are added without issue. Idea is i need to cast in my function EquipItem, not Item. AddItem got 2 functions, one takes Item, another EquipItem. And if my type of current Item another, not Item, but it's child - EquipItem, UseItem, i need to cast my Items[i] as a EquipItem, while Items - array of Item and obviously using all as just Item.

Comment: @MirBot - thats what the update was about. So whatever is adding your item to the list also calls `item.AddedToList()` - that code doesnt know what type of `Item` it is but thats what the `virtual`/`override` is all about - as someone commented this is the very basics of polymorphism, which is a subject I think you probably want to read up on.